# finding k triangles that connect all vertices with minimum weight in a undirected complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

For a complete undirected graph, each edge has a positive weight. My problem is to find a way to collect K triangles including all vertices from all triangles in the graph so that the sum of weight on edges of K triangles is minimum. 
The question is like MST. But I want to get more redundancy. Does this algorithm exist?

Comment: Can you clarify what this, "including all vertices from all triangles in the graph" means? Do you want the triangles to give you a connected subgraph? Only to contain all vertices? Something else?

Also, do you want exactly K triangles? Or would a cheaper setup containing less thank K triangles work?

Comment: Hi Todor, yes, this means the edges connect all of the vertices. I need all vertices are connected each other. I hope more triangles can be found in the graph so that closure among any three vertices can be achieved. Maybe finding K triangles is not easy, it would be acceptable if triangles are constructed as many as possible.